# Result from summary in xtable

Tags: xtable

I have a vector of values, and I want to use the output of "summary" in LaTeX. I understand that `xtable` is designed for exactly that purpose.

However ...

```
> values <- c(1,2,3)
> summary(values)
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
1.0     1.5     2.0     2.0     2.5     3.0 
> xtable(summary(values))
Error in xtable.table(summary(values)) : 
  xtable.table is not implemented for tables of > 2 dimensions
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because `xtable` would be happier if you were summarising a dataframe rather than a vector. Try this instead:

```
values <- c(1,2,3)
values <- data.frame(x=values)
xtable(summary(values))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
xtable(data.frame(summary(values[1:6])))
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  The answer would be improved by adding some explanation or a reference to where there is relevant documentation.